# ASP.NET VB Listview assign ID to a table row

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

What I want to do is assign an ID to a table row with value of a ID of the column in question.

To clarify. I have a data table with fields `[ID]` `[Name]` `[Description]`, and populate the `ListView` like this: (I've simplified the code here for clarity)

```
<asp:ListView ID="MainList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id">
    <layouttemplate>
        <dl id="header">
            <dd class="rowHeader">Name</dd>
            <dd class="rowHeader">Description</dd>
        </dl>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder">
        </asp:Panel>
    </layouttemplate>
    <itemtemplate>
        <dl class="row">
            <dd><%# Eval("name")%></dd>
            <dd><%# Eval("description")%></dd>
        </dl>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Now, what I tried was to add it like this.

```
<dl class="row" id='<%# Eval("id")%>'>
```

and of course it worked, but I need to pass it as a variable because i need to check for something with it. Like so:

```
<% Dim id as Integer = Eval("id") %>
<dl class="row" id='<%=id %>'>
```

I got this error:

```
Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.
```

And I get it why... the reason why I need this is so I can compare id with a session variable and change rows class accordingly.

Any way to go around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do the same type of logic in your class attribute:

```
<dl class="row" id='<%# Eval("id")%>' class='<%= Eval("id") == Session["myValue"] ? "someCssClass" : "otherCssClass" %>'>
```

I think this should work.

Comment: same error... I had to use different syntax since here you used C# inline if, this is VB as tagged :)

Comment: worked. thanks :) i made a mistake in setting it up :D

`<dl id='<%# Eval("id") %>' class='<%# IIf(Eval("id") = Session("temp"), "row selectedRow", "row") %>'>`

This was the exact code for vb.